# How to create One ThreadPoolExecutor per user?

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool

I have a requirement where we have to create `ThreadPoolExecutor` for per tenant. Concurrently I am using Spring given `@Async` Annotation but that is for whole application. So if the server is busy with one tenant, it will affect the other user's tenant. `@Async` is configured with `ThreadPoolExecutor`.
But it is common for all users across tenant.

EDIT :
I need Thread Pool for per Tenant.
In simply language, I need to share ThreadPool for the group of users. All the users from that group can use the same threadPool.

How is that possible with existing java API's. Please Help.

How to seperate out ThreadPool for Tenants?
For Ex : Tenant 1 is assigned some 20 threads, so all users (U1,U2....) can use that threadPool and it will not affect another tenant.
Same with Tenant 2, it will be assigned some 20 threads....

Comment: How many users are you expecting, because that will turn bad really fast.

Comment: if the threadpool of a single **user A** uses all available resources (CPU, RAM, FileSystem etc) then every other user *still* has to wait until the tasks of **user A** are finished and have free'd up the resources

Comment: I have edited the question. I need it for Tenant which contains Users. And we have multiple tenants, where users are performing heavy processing.

Answer (score 0):

Not to discuss whether it is a "good requirement" or not - easy-peasy:

1. (Extend `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` in a custom class and...) add a `@SessionScope`d `@Bean` of it to your application context.
2. Use it. (In controllers via @Async annotation)

Like:

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.annotation.SessionScope;

@Component
@SessionScope
public class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {

   // only for test-/debuging
   static volatile int cnt = 0;

   public MyThreadPoolExecutor() {
      // only for test-/debuging
      System.out.format("MyThreadPoolExecutor#%d%n", cnt++);
   }
}
```

Using it in a simple controller like this:

```
@Async // !
@GetMapping("/hello")
@ResponseBody
public Future<String> hello() {
    return new AsyncResult("Hello");
}
```

..I get MyThreadPoolExecutor logging, when (and only when) using a new incognito browser/session/user.

Comment: How to do it tenant wise? like Tenant1 (40 threads) -> all users of Tenant 1 can use it from 40 threads, same with  Tenant2(40)

Comment: There is no need to create a custom extension. Just write an `@Bean` method that creates the session scoped bean.

Comment: I have edited my question. OK....But how do you share the ThreadPool to the group of users?

Comment: ..this is a more complex requirement since there is no (predefined) "tenant-scope" in spring...

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-scope ! ;) (and guess how they named their "custom scope"!?)

Comment: it says: "it's generally considered a bad practice to override the web-aware scopes. **However** ..", but what you would need (to glue this with my original answer), would be an "extended SessionScope", which resolves according tenant from session/user...the rest could work "as is".

Comment: Didn't get that extended SessionScope part. Do i have to extends its functionality? How? Can you elaborate more in the answer..